# Normally distributed: examples like LTCM

Tags: references, normality-assumption, teaching

I am looking for examples of organizations suffering dire consequences (losing money) because they have assumed that something was normally distributed hence underestimating the risk of tail events.
The classical textbook example is [LTCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-Term_Capital_Management). I'd be interesting in seeing other examples outside the financial services industry.

Thanks!